# Asus X550L Weak Wifi signal ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, asus

I'm new to Ubuntu OS. I've installed ubuntu 14.04 x64 on my ASUS X550LC laptop yesterday.
The wifi signal is weak & getting disconnected sometimes.

Searched all over the web but many site/forums has discussed with Atheros network adapter but the one I have is Ralink RT3290.

This what my `iwconfig` gives:

```
ppp0      no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
usbpn0    no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
```

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Hello, Here it is: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7820982/

Comment: I added more directions to my answer all you have to do is copy the code into the terminal one line at a time then reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to install the 3290 driver go [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7kbO9nS2qKEMmQ5elZXVUhDRjA/edit) and download the driver then:

We need to install some prerequisites to be able to compile the new driver.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
```

We need to change to the directory the driver was downloaded too which should be the downloads folder.

Please copy and paste all commands one line at a time for accuracy:

```
cd Downloads
```

Now untar the driver to `/usr/src directory`

```
 sudo tar -xf rt3290sta-2.6.0.0.dkms.tar -C /usr/src
```

then do:

```
sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force
echo "blacklist rt2800pci" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist rt2x00pci" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot.
The directions to install come from the readme file of the driver and my own.

Now, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, I have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz.

I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-fits-all setting. Find yours here: [Country Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: [IPV6 setting](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png)  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: Thank you very much, the signal seems to be improved now. :)
But, It is still getting disconnected frequently. And its not the with the router/ISP because the windows laptop next to time  is working perfectly. Any Idea about that?

Comment: How often does it disconnect? Run the script again with the new driver and post the results.

Comment: It is almost getting disconnected & connected repeatedly every minute or so. Here is the code http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7823213/

Comment: I edited my answer to include settings in the router that have a great impact on linux being able to connect and function properly.

Comment: Hello again, It seemed to work then but afterwards it started to disconnect again. It is loosing the signal or disconnected every few minutes (around 5-10 mins). Here's the link again.. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7847358. Please help.