# Wifi strength very weak in ubuntu

Tags: wireless

I am using an HP product with wireless lan interface details as follows-

```
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 14:2d:27:d2:94:0f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) ip=192.168.1.34 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:b5500000-b5507fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 08
       serial: 6c:c2:17:5e:0b:a4
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:58 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
```

When I am sitting just next to router then also only two signals showing up on my wifi.
Please help me...

Comment: Which kernel are you using (please provide `uname -a`)? 3.17.x mainline kernel showed great improvement after I tried different devices (Intel, Realtek, ASIX) in the same situation (sitting just next to the hot spot and having very low connection quality).

Comment: Linux aditya-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This is the output of the command

Comment: If you can, edit the question and delete your comments to make it readable. Do you have the possiblity to test a mainline kernel (following instructions at http://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)?

Answer (score 2):

## Maybe your wifi is set to power saving?

power.d >
set the wifi to no power savings.

```
iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Check this out:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower

## Another option - driver issue:

Check this out:
[Asus X550L Weak Wifi signal ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499953/asus-x550l-weak-wifi-signal-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I have tried this before, but no correction, I have read about the same problem with other people as well but could not find a correct solution.

Comment: There is some problem with the drivers of my wireless device. Broadcom BCM43142. Please help me out

Comment: Try those solutions: http://kb.openstudioproject.com/content/ubuntu/install-broadcom-bcm43142-driver-ubuntu or https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1308505

Comment: that command did not work in Ubuntu 16.04